# Send Php Variable with jquery to php script

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send a variable with jquery to a php script now this is my first try after reading the documentation but it wont work. can anyone give me some advice ? I didn't realize the error in code. The variable I want to send is $id. I defined it with '1'

```
<?php
$id = '1';
?>
```

jquery part

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    // Anfang Dokument Ready Funktion
$("p").click(function () {  // Anfang Klick Funktion
 var id = $(this).html();    // Inhalt in Klickfunktion
// Beginn Ajax Segment mit Angabe von Typ Url Data und Div #ausgabe
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/ajax.php',
        data: 'id='+id',
        success: function(data){
            $('#ausgabe').html(data);
        }
        });     // Ende Ajax Segment 
});    // Ende Klick Funktion
});  // Ende Dokument Ready Funktion
</script>

<div id="ausgabe"></div>
<p><button>Sende Variable</button></p>
```

The ajax.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['id]'` is a syntax error; try exchanging the `'` and `]`

Comment: change id='+id' to "id":id

Comment: uh... no... don't fix that within the question itself; you might invalidate the question (it will probably be deleted anyways, but still...)

Answer (score 0):

The right form to send info with ajax to PHP is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/ajax.php',
        data: id:id,
        success: function(data){
            $('#ausgabe').html(data);
        }
        });
```

To send by reference.
If you want to send without reference just use:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/ajax.php',
        data: id,
        success: function(data){
            $('#ausgabe').html(data);
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rely on `data-*` attributes better:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Click me</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){

  $('a[data-id]').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    // $(this).data('id') fetches the data-id attribute from your anchor
    $.post( someUrl, { id : $(this).data('id')} ).done(function(){ ... })

  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Send it like this

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/ajax.php',
        data: {id : <?php echo $id ?>},
        success: function(data){
            $('#ausgabe').html(data);
        }
        });     // Ende Ajax Segment
```

Comment: data: {id : <?php echo $id ?>},
this is not good practice, include php code into js. it will be better to use data tag or in a input field and then get it by element

Comment: but this is the only way how it works for me now however the other ways wont work in one case i get an error undefined index in the other no result